# MariaDB conditional unique constraint per foreign key

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have a table `Stuff`, that has extra information in the table `Heighness`. `Heighness` has a foreign key to `Stuff` and a column `level`. The column `level` may have a limitless occurence of the same values per foreign key to `Stuff`, except only max *one* occurence of the value `topMost` per foreign key to `Stuff`. So that each occurence of `Stuff` may have only one `Heighness` element which is counted as `topMost`. The `level` column must always be set to a value (Non-Null).

Can MariaDB have constraints for that? Like this:

```
Stuff-Table
| ID | ... |
+----+-----+
| 3  | ... |
| 4  | ... |

Heighness-Table
| ID | Stuff_id | level    |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |     3    | mediocre | 
|  2 |     3    | mediocre | <-- As it's not "topMost", as many as you want.
|  3 |     3    | topMost  | <-- Perfect, only 0 to 1 occurences.

|  4 |     4    | topMost  | <-- 2nd occurence absolute, but only 1st per foreign key. Nice.
|  5 |     4    | low      |
|  6 |     4    | topMost  | <-- 2 occurences per foreign key! Error! MariaDB should block this!
```

MariaDB 10.6 has unique indices, but not filtered unique indices, checks and unique constraints, it seems that isn't enough and I would've fall back to triggers, what I would like to avoid.

Am I wrong? Is there a combination of UNIQUE and CHECK constraints that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) which is unique for `topMost` and not `mediocre` and create a unique index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE Heighness
ADD uqLevel varbinary(12) AS ( CONCAT(Stuff_id, '-', LEFT(level, 1), IF(level= topMost, Stuff_id, ID)) )
  PERSISTENT UNIQUE
```

This generates for the table:

```
3-m1
3-m2
3-t3

4-t4
4-l5
4-t4 - This is a duplicate.
```

A normal FK constaint additionally with ensure `Stuff_id` is in the `Sutff` table

Comment: Genius answer. Didn't even know MariaDB could do that.